# Visual Studio DockerfileBuildArguments with enviroment variables not works

Tags: visual-studio, docker

In docker i need to pass 2 arguments for restore my private nuget packages

```
docker build -t backend-template --build-arg ARTIFACTS_PAT=My-pat --build-arg ARTIFACTS_ENDPOINT=My-endpoint .
```

When i pass this arguments on `DockerfileBuildArguments` tag in `api.csproj` as environment variables the build not works
[image]
[image]

This is the command that VS runs

```
docker build -f "C:\Users\matmahnke\Documents\repos\myproject\Dockerfile" --force-rm -t ymstemplatebackendapi:dev --target build --build-arg ARTIFACTS_PAT= --build-arg ARTIFACTS_ENDPOINT= --label "com.microsoft.created-by=visual-studio" --label "com.microsoft.visual-studio.project-name=myproject.api" "C:\Users\matmahnke\Documents\repos\myproject"
```

I need it to be an environment variable to add to gitignore

Answer (score 0):

Per the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/containers/container-launch-settings?view=vs-2022), the description of "environmentVariables" reads "These environment variable values are passed to the process **when** it's launched in the container."

Note the "when", so these environment variables aren't available for the `docker build`.

You can still accomplish what you want by setting an environment variable outside of Visual Studio, viz. For Windows 10 this can be done as so:

1. Windows Settings -> System -> About -> Advanced system settings -> Environment Variables -> <New...> under "User variables for..."
2. Or just search for "Environment" in the Start search and it should come up.

Once set you can reference as expected in the .csproj:

```xml
<PropertyGroup>
  <DockerfileBuildArguments>--build-arg "ACCESS_TOKEN=$(ARTIFACTSPAT)"</DockerfileBuildArguments>
</PropertyGroup>
```